# How to create Mac OS X Application Bundle with Eclipse to MacOS Catalina

Tags: java, eclipse, bundle, macos-catalina

I am trying to export my java Mac OS X application bundle. But when I run it I get an error saying that I need Java 6 for Mac OS X.

When I ran `java -version` on Terminal it returned this:

```
java version "13.0.1" 2019-10-15
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 13.0.1+9)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 13.0.1+9, mixed mode, sharing)`
```

Is Eclipse not up to date with Apple or am I exporting my project wrong?

Thank you!

Comment: Judging by [this bug report](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=431950) the export is completely broken.

Answer (score -1):

This is a long standing issue with Eclipse on macOS, usually fixed by adding some missing values to the JVMCapabilities key in

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/<your_java_version>/Contents/Info.plist
```

so it finally looks:

```
<key>JVMCapabilities</key>
 <array>
  <string>JNI</string>
  <string>BundledApp</string>
  <string>WebStart</string>
  <string>Applets</string>
  <string>CommandLine</string>
 </array>
```